# How to add Picker View in Self view

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a problem in adding Picker View:

```
-(void)addPickerView{
   UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init] ;
    pickerView.frame=CGRectMake(10, 75, 180,180);
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;

    UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
    toolbar.frame=CGRectMake(0,75,180,10);
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpaceLeft = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem* doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneClicked:)];
    [toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexibleSpaceLeft, doneButton, nil]];


    [pickerView addSubview:toolbar];
  [self.view addSubview:pickerView];

}
```

It is my Picker View With Done ToolBar Button. But there is a problem whenever I call the `AddPickerView` Method:

> Application is Crashed

Now what I do?

**EDIT**

Here is the reason of the crash

> 2015-02-03 18:45:47.772 iCricketScore[2040:106045] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000012

Comment: Do you want to add the toolbar as the subview of the pickerView?

Comment: yes can you help me about this /

Comment: I don't think you can use UIPickerView this way.  You use UIPickerView to choose between a set of discreet options, you could try to embed the UIPickerView inside of a toolbar but not the other way around like you are trying above

Comment: it is better to create a UIView, and add to it the pickerView and the Toolbar.